# Is reconstituing Stack Overflow data (as an FAQ site) ok?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

I stumbled across [this site](http://programmingfaq.w3ec.com/faq/86871/iphone-nsurlconnection-simultaneous-requests-limit) which takes Stack Overflow questions, and gives the answer or the top voted answer.

The main point of the site seems to be to shower you with adverts.

With the CC wiki license I'm assuming they're ok to do this. Or does it break copyright?

Comment: Sounds familiar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers

Comment: "an eff aye cue"?

Comment: @shog9 roffle I can't correct it now

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing not. Considering the license on StackOverflow clearly states that there should be attribution

If anything, the horrible design should get it shut down.

Edit: I guess there is a statement on the home page stating it was from Stack Overflow, although I still think it pretty shaky...

Comment: Wouldn't attribution have to cover the authors of the questions and answers also?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, what a useless site. It doesn't attempt to do anything interesting with the dump data, but just throws it up in a totally unnavigatable (sp!) format.

Comment: Abusing advertising revenue streams ftw!