# efreedom.com-- Another SO ripped-off?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did anyone notice that tech.efreedom.com seem to be scraping/republishing SO's posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/did-anyone-notice-that-tech-efreedom-com-seem-to-be-scraping-republishing-sos-po)

It seems that [efreedom.com is ripping off the content from SO](http://efreedom.com/Question/1-3650449/Griddata-Cubic-Interpolation-Method-Returns-NaN). The reason I said this is because my SO question ends up exactly at there, and it ranks higher than SO in Google search!!

Is efreedom.com using the SO content freely and fairly?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/did-anyone-notice-that-tech-efreedom-com-seem-to-be-scraping-republishing-sos-po

Answer (score 4):

It looks fine.  They're noting and linking the license (cc-wiki/CC-BY-SA 2.5), attributing and linking the user, and linking to the StackOverflow question page.  The bottom of each page says where the content comes from.

Comment: The bottom of the page contains a copyright notice.  You'd have to wonder on what, I don't see anything that's not covered by cc-wiki.

Comment: @Hans, it should be clearer, but they do hold copyrights on some parts, such as their logo graphic.