# Why these scrapers have higher ranks than the original stackoverflow pages in Google search results?

Tags: discussion, google, screen-scraping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did anyone notice that tech.efreedom.com seem to be scraping/republishing SO's posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/did-anyone-notice-that-tech-efreedom-com-seem-to-be-scraping-republishing-sos-po)

Sites like answerspice.com and efreedom.com are not only stealing our thunder but also making a lot of noises which makes our searches less effective.

Try http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ipad+uitextfield+dismiss+keyboard&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Sometimes our original page even does not show on the first page.

Are you going to work this out with Google? Or are these scrapers liable to any restriction by law?

Comment: Probably tons of hidden links and text, I guess.

Comment: I would disagree that this is a duplicate.  It's asking about search result rankings, not pointing out that they exist.

Comment: I agree with @jjnguy. I'd rather see this question on `seo.stackexchange.com` than MSO, though.

Comment: This question should be closed, but because it's off topic not a duplicate. It's a SEO question. EDIT: damn, here we go. I voted as "off topic" though.