# First tag in the title of the page is not that convenient

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags, seo

After some recent changes whenever I open a question the page title reads `<first-question-tag>-<question title>-Stack Overflow`.

Tags are often quite long - for example there's `visual-studio-2008` tag on SO. If browser uses tabs the tag might occupy all the tab width and no room for actual question title is left - this makes navigating between tabs inconvenient.

Comment: Related (on Webmasters):  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/6556/46

Comment: +1 for idea, even tho I know _why_ it's being done in the first place. @JeffAtwood (when you get around to this one) doesn't appending them work as well as prepending them?

Comment: @drachenstern: No, tags placed earlier in the `<title>` have more weight (for confirmation see Rebecca's link, above) so prepending is optimal.

Comment: @Robert ~ Are you _serious_? **OY** that SUCKS ~~~~ Guess that makes this [status-by-design] then and not likely to go away...

Comment: This wouldn't be nearly as inconvenient if the default maximum tab size was about 25% larger.

Comment: IMO "not that convenient" is not strong enough. Personally I think the tag-in-title is downright annoying, and sometimes confusing. I hope it can be just a temporary change.

Comment: -1, sorry - content-scraping sites do precisely this so that they rank higher, and we have to fight fire with fire. It would be an SEO disaster to not do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, this is absolutely necessary, otherwise we get *demolished* by scrapers using our own content in Google ranking.

For background you can read:
http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1985264

And:

- http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/12721357573857280
- http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/12778297536552960
- http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/12963460203679744

As for "why not at the end of the title versus at the start", see

[Does the order of keywords matter in a page title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title)

Comment: I'm not convinced that the best way to combat competition is to make your own site inconvenient to use...

Comment: @sth that's not the only thing we are doing, but honestly, if Google isn't enforcing their "no original content" rule, our hands are tied. http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66361

Comment: Jeff, did you ever get a hold of Matt Cutts at Google? http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1986396

Comment: @ray yes, but he's looking at a different problem for us. This was the 90% primary problem, but there is a 10% secondary problem as well. See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5385/page-appears-indexed-in-google-but-not-findable-for-any-search-terms

Comment: See also [Please disable displaying a tag at the start of page titles - Meta Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/777/please-disable-displaying-a-tag-at-the-start-of-page-titles)

Comment: Couldn't the title be left the old way for logged-in users and just use the new way for logged-out users (including googlebot)? I wouldn't think that'd be considered cloaking since it's not just visible to crawlers, even if that's the major reason for doing it in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone not aware of the problem with this, and why this "solution" exists for the "problem" that most users familiar with SO don't know about:

[Report high-Google-ranking Stack Exchange content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-scrapers-here)

> quoting meta (so meta, no?)
>
> > for those of you seeing scrapers rank
> >     above #stackoverflow can you reply
> >     with your exact google query terms?
> >     (plain text only, no urls) Tweeted by
> >     codinghorror on December 9, 2010 at
> >     7:59 AM

and

[What to do when you find copied SF, SU or SO content on other websites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50192/what-to-do-when-you-find-copied-sf-su-or-so-content-on-other-websites)

[Why these scrapers have higher ranks than the original stackoverflow pages in Google search results?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70410/why-these-scrapers-have-higher-ranks-than-the-original-stackoverflow-pages-in-goo)

Comment: The SO Clones link doesn't list SO scrapers like efreedom and comanswer, but only UI clones.

Comment: @BalusC ~ I finally had time to update my answer. Sorry.