# How does Stack Overflow know what is the main tag of a question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Which tag is added to the page title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title)
>   [Does it matter the order you tag your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77808/does-it-matter-the-order-you-tag-your-question)

In the browser's title bar, Stack Overflow always displays one of the question's tags first. Often it seems that it actually picks the most relevant. Is that the case? Are they somehow analyzing the post's content to pick the main tag? Or does it pick one at random?

Comment: Also see: [Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions), [Why is the least important tag in the title of this StackExchange page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72377/), [First tag in the title of the page is not that convenient](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/), [First tag in the title of the page is not that convenient. - Part two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84661/)