# Share on Facebook shows the low-ranking designed title tag

Tags: discussion, facebook

[image]

The title looks weird, "history - Who is...". Given that it's going to Facebook, the chances of it being farmed would be pretty low (I only have 71 "friends"), and it reads really weirdly.

Should the Facebook Share titles be changed back to the normal, un-adultered titles?

<sub>For the record, [I know why the titles have been mangled in such a way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient), and it makes sense for the people who are farming content from the Internet, but it's not a great look when you actually want to share the content.</sub>

Comment: Incidentally, when you share a link on Facebook, you have the ability to edit the title and description before hitting the "Share Link" button. _credit to [@msh210](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8099782#8099782)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not from us sending it to Facebook -- AFAIK that is from Facebook deciding on its own to use the `<title>` tag on the question.

We definitely don't send that.

Comment: I know that you can specify facebook-specific meta-tags in the page documents - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ - might be worth a look. Although to be honest, this is the first time I've ever felt inclined to use the facebook integration, so whether it's worth it or not depends on how many people are using it I guess.

Comment: According to [Facebook's debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11227809%2Fwhy-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array), StackExchange is not specifying OpenGraph values for _title_, _description_, and _image_. So Facebook just takes what's available.

Comment: @HodofHod correct, because we didn't want to bloat every page with three extra headers that are useful 0.01% of the time.

Comment: @Jeff, That makes sense, but I was under the impression that sites can change their content based on the user agent (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626812/how-to-recognize-facebook-user-agent). Is this impractical here?