# Remove tag in question title for logged-in users

Tags: feature-request, tags, title

We all hate the tags in the html page title, but they seem to be necessary for SEO: [First tag in the title of the page is not that convenient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient). Scraper sites used to destroy stackoverflow in the Google rankings.

However, as it looks like we're stuck with this, this seems like a prime candidate to remove for logged-in users.

This would do away with the annoying problem of having the tags in the title and would not affect the SEO rating, because Google would still see the same page as before and logged-in users would have a much nicer experience.

Comment: I actually wonder how much recent changes in Google's algorithm might have affected this. Maybe adding keywords to the title is not necessary anymore at all.