# When are tags included in the HTML title of the question page?

Tags: support, tags, title, help-center, search-engine

I see that there are **two ways to derive the HTML title** from the question. Here some "random" examples.

### Tag-prefixed question:

- [c - format string vulnerability - printf - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672996/format-string-vulnerability-printf)
- [classloader - java Class Loader - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894532/java-class-loader)
- [java - Eclipse WTP vs sydeo, " serves modules without publishing " - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123782/eclipse-wtp-vs-sydeo-serves-modules-without-publishing)

### Solely the question:

- [printf vs cout in C++ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c)
- [Measuring Documentation Coverage with Doxygen - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938760/measuring-documentation-coverage-with-doxygen)
- [How to build Visual Studio 2012 Publishing Profiles on a Build Server with MsBuild without installing Visual Studio 2012 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176894/how-to-build-visual-studio-2012-publishing-profiles-on-a-build-server-with-msbui)

It's of course relevant for googling questions, so what are **the rules behind it?** I read something about "the most relevant tag" - but since this may vary depending on the question text, can it be decided automatically?

I'm neither for nor against tags in titles, I only want to **understand the logic** behind it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most popular tag in the question is added to the HTML title, if it isn't found in the actual question title.

> c - format string vulnerability - printf - Stack Overflow

C isn't found in the actual title, add it as a prefix.

> Measuring Documentation Coverage with Doxygen - Stack Overflow

Doxygen is mentioned in the title, no need to add it.

> classloader - java Class Loader - Stack Overflow

Java is mentioned in the question title itself, so check for the next most popular tag in the question: classloader isn't mentioned (note the white space) so add it to the title.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. This mechanism seems logical. Which resource did you use?

Comment: @Wolf it's something that has come up on chat a few times, and the related questions mention at least some of these.

Comment: Is there no "official" description on some help page?

Comment: @Wolf I'm not aware of any, but I don't read those pages too often.

Comment: I had a look, but found nothing like this. And here both fail: the SO internal search AND google ;) Maybe that's by purpose ([First tag in the title of the page is not that convenient - Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient?rq=1), [seo - Does the order of keywords matter in a page title? - Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title))...