# Are external sites allowed to copy content from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did anyone notice that tech.efreedom.com seem to be scraping/republishing SO's posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/did-anyone-notice-that-tech-efreedom-com-seem-to-be-scraping-republishing-sos-po)

I have already seen these sites that are verbatim copies of Wikipedia's content, but was unaware that the same exists for Stack Overflow until I ran into this http://www.questionhub.com/StackOverflow/.

Now my question: Is this even allowed?