# Globberstack copying questions from Stack Overflow word for word

Tags: discussion, copyright, attribution, copyright-infringement

I was recently researching a question I asked on Stack Overflow by using Google. I typed in a query similiar to the question I had posted on Stack Overflow.

Surprise surprise, there was my question in Google, five search results down. The only problem was that this question was hosted on globberstack.com.

The question was posted by 'topdog,' who has posted over 18531 questions. It was word for word my question, even including my signoff as Tim.

Clearly, this is a blatant breach of copyright, and I am unsure if the Stack Overflow developers and community are already aware of this.

Comment: Could you post the link? But don't post it as a link, just as text (we don't want Google to pick it up as an inbound link for these guys).

Comment: Welcome to Meta, Tim!  Your question has essentially been asked before.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers contains an answer to your question and a "master list" of sites that copy off of SO.  I'm voting to close your question as a duplicate, just to keep all the info in one place.  Good catch, though!

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49891/stackoverflow-questions-turning-up-on-answerspice-com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see Jeff's recent blog post titled [Defending Attribution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/) for more information about this problem and how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want done about that?  If it's your question, it's your copyright, and you would have to be the one to take action.

If you and globberstack.com are in the US, you could send a DMCA takedown notice.  Here's [Google's rules](http://www.google.com/dmca.html) on how to send one.  If not, you could email them and point out the problem.

Of course, your question is available to be used elsewhere, but only with attribution.  Look at the Creative Commons license information on the bottom of the page.