# Someone is ripping off Stack Overflow's questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

SO questions are showing up at `answerspice.com`.

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49891/stack-overflow-questions-turning-up-on-answerspice-com