# What to do when you find copied SF, SU or SO content on other websites?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, legal, screen-scraping, copycat-sites

Recently, while answering a Server Fault question, I stumbled upon a copied Server Fault question and answer at what looks like a content aggregation or text scraping site.

- Here's the original thread: [SPF include: too many IP addresses](https://serverfault.com/questions/129127/spf-include-too-many-ip-addresses)
- Here's the copied site: `http://www.answerspice.com/c118/1787456/spf-include-too-many-ip-addresses`

To be fair, the "copied" site gives attribution to all of its scraped content. However, this brought up an interesting topic in my mind which led to three questions:

1. Is there even an offense if a site scrapes trilogy content or are we all just one big GPL family?
2. If this is an offense, does attribution (such as what AnswerSpice does) lessen the offense in cases like this?
3. What is the proper thing to do if a site is found to be scraping content from one of the trilogy sites in a way that is not allowed?

Comment: See Jeff's [post here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962) to report these.

Comment: Bah! And here I thought I had scoured the site sufficiently. =(

Comment: This might not be a scrape, the could be using the data dump.

Comment: again, please don't link to the scrapers unless they properly attribute (none so far do, with 1 possible rare exception)