# Add method to expand tags when used in the page title

Tags: feature-request, tags, seo

Some of the tags we are forced to use on Gaming.SE are fairly awkward or acronymirific because of the plague of sequelitis rampant in the industry. As a result, it seems like our SEO can be pretty terrible at times, even if the tag we pick looks the best to us in our own little vacuum.

- [Rename [star-wars-tor] → [star-wars-old-republic]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/rename-star-wars-tor-star-wars-old-republic)
- [Rename [star-wars-old republic] → [swtor]?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3574/rename-star-wars-old-republic-swtor)
- [SEO for AC: Revelations](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/seo-for-ac-revelations)
- [How should we tag Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/how-should-we-tag-ratchet-clank-all-4-one)

A longer tag length would be nice (say—double), but as a possible alternative, how about allowing an alternative expansion of the tag name when it's [added to the page's HTML title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71982/scrapers-enter-the-scene-was-the-choice-of-license-right/71984#71984)?

I'm trying to draw some (distant) parallel to [Wikipedia's DISPLAYTITLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:DISPLAYTITLE#Changing_the_displayed_title) where some code in the article can be used to change the title appearance.

Here perhaps it could work where the tag expands into [random **terrible ideas**].

- Whatever the first first-level heading in the tag wiki is (perhaps with the strict constraint it's the very first thing on the page)
- Whatever is in some *magic code* on the tag wiki
- Whatever is in a new "Title" field

If nothing fulfills whatever criteria, it just uses the tag as it does now.

In any case, the result would be that some question tagged [swtor](/questions/tagged/swtor), for example, would have "Star Wars: The Old Republic" in the page (HTML) title, in lieu of acronym-rich gamer jargon.  I don't think such abbreviations are functionally bad, they just look bad.

Some cases *may* actually be worse: in looking at some [PlayStation tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8415/can-should-we-reverse-the-playstation-tag-synonyms-psx-playstation-x) and how they get parsed when Googling, it's not immediately apparent that `ps4` == `playstation 4`.  In any event, the proper title could be omitted or modified to reflect the best SEO option.

Comment: I think getting rid of the double tag thing would go nicely with this (presuming it's actually the game tag that gets put in the title).

Comment: @BobCratchit do you mean how Gaming.SE uses the top 2 tags vs. 1 in our title?  That's beyond the scope of this idea as it is, though perhaps a tag with an explicit title/name could somehow override a more common one (hrm...)

Comment: Personally I *hate* tags in the title, unless they are absolutely necessary... after a quick look at gaming.se, I have to ask: how much of a problem is this really? On the active questions page, I see zero questions using the cryptic swtor tag in the title.

Comment: @slugster I mean [the `<title>`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71982/scrapers-enter-the-scene-was-the-choice-of-license-right/71984#71984)

Comment: Good suggestion IMO.

Comment: @Nick, that clarifies it, thanks :)

Comment: @BobCratchit: To get the game name in the title only, we'd need an important tag feature, which Jeff vetoed.