# What is www.developerit.com?

Tags: discussion, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

I accidentally found this site [www.developerit.com](http://www.developerit.com) and I could see the my StackOverflow Q & A in that site. And I can see it is a site that does too many advertising. I am always automatically redirected to Advertisements. Is it an authorized site? What I can do if I don't like to see my Q & A in google as a developerIT post not an SO one?

Comment: may be they already know that, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962

Comment: Yeah, I added that site to Jeff's repository answer about a week ago. They have a slight terms-of-use violation with regards to SOFU content, but a violation nevertheless.