# What should you do if other sites shamelessly copy content and the cc-wiki license is not adhered to?

Tags: support, copyright, licensing, copyright-infringement

Copying content is one thing, but copying content without referring to or quoting the original is just plain rude and violates the cc-wiki license and the clearly laid out [attribution rules](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) of this and related sites.

When someone or some site does this, what action should we undertake towards the SO team to signal this? Should we worry at all?

- Example of a full-copy [of a post and its thread][2] without linking back, violating cc-wiki and claiming it under their own cc-wiki.
  `http://www.answerspice.com/c119/1540246/what-can-you-do-in-msil-that-you-cannot-do-in-c%23-or-vbnet`
- Example of [the same post and only the accepted answer][3], with correctly linking back.
  `http://efreedom.com/Question/1-541936/What-can-you-do-in-MSIL-that-you-cannot-do-in-C#-or-vb-NET`
- The same [original question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541936).

Comment: They do link to Stack Overflow in the "This is only an excerpt.... go to the original site" paragraph. It's not in full compliance with the license though.

Comment: @Pekka: Yes, well hidden, I only saw it at third read. But indeed, it is not conforming the rules as described [in this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962) and [by Jeff on his blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to the list here:

[Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

We're collating all the links and we'll be doing something with them soon — they should follow the rules of the attribution license.

Comment: Done! Apparently, answerspice does that with more questions. Recently they have added the text "this is just an excerpt, read the full...", but still don't follow the guidelines, see this question: `http://www.answerspice.com/c119/1586623/how-do-you-use-the-ellipsis-slicing-syntax-in-python`. Good to see that you're taking care of these leeches!