# Vampires sucking Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, copyright, licensing

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What should you do if other sites shamelessly copy content and the cc-wiki license is not adhered to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59230/what-should-you-do-if-other-sites-shamelessly-copy-content-and-the-cc-wiki-licens)
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

Can't you guys do something to prevent vampires like this

`http://www.developerit.com/2010/06/17/malloc-to-a-cgpoint-pointer-throwing-exc_bad_access-
when-accessing`

versus

[Malloc to a CGPoint Pointer throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063862/malloc-to-a-cgpoint-pointer-throwing-exc-bad-access-when-accessing)

from stealing content from Stack Overflow and put on their pages?
The problem is that they get top positions on google and sometimes the original question on SO not even appears on first pages on google.

We google, we found them and the losers just put the question, not the answers, so we lost hours seen thousands of useless links on their site. Everybody loses.

They even put there where they get the content.

C'mon guys, block these losers.

Comment: @Ether See the page. It's adhered to.

Comment: I thought this was a weblog post

Comment: @Juan - that's what you get for parsing HTML with regular expressions without using JQuery.

Comment: Someone claiming to be from the site in question replied to another similar question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/55142#55142

Comment: you can help by not linking to them.

Comment: They can't spell either - "Who's amung us?" saywhat?

Answer (score 2):

There's proper attribution, so I don't see anything wrong with it. The licence under which Stackoverflow content is publish allows this.

Comment: the problem is that SO is being buried by these vampires and the user, that should benefit from SO vast knowledge base is not finding SO. The user is finding them. Stack Overflow will suffer over time, losing revenue or whatever and not being able to invest and improve more and more. I care because I like SO but If SO is comfortable about being stolen, so, I rest my case.

Comment: @Mike - CC-BY-SA is CC-BY-SA. Don't doubt for a minute that sites that just publish carbon copies of SO won't be buried quickly by Google and other search engines, just like clones of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Who cares? Once you put something on the net, it can and will be accessed and reused on multiple sites. If that's a problem for you, don't use the internet.

Comment: So if I say gravity makes things fall downwards, I will now get downvoted by people who want to flap their arms to fly? Well, OK, I suppose.

Comment: Probably the best argument yet against on-line dating.

Comment: @Tim That would be the arm-flapping. I hate those women that do that.

Comment: @Neil - Oh man, you met LadyBigBird1999 also? What did you do when she started ... ugh, I can't even talk about it.