# "copyright" and QuestionHub harvesting questions from SO

Tags: discussion, questions, copyright, content-reuse

Hi all, while browsing desperatly online hoping to find answers to a [question I asked](https://superuser.com/questions/173963/huge-latency-in-ubuntu-network-connectivity-on-asus-eee-1001ha-ubuntu-10-4-luci), I found my own question on google (fair enough) and on [this website](http://www.questionhub.com/SuperUser/173963) named "QuestionHub". Their tagline reads

> QuestionHub gathers questions from
>   leading sites, helping you to quickly
>   and effectively find answers.

what's the deal with this stuff? Did SU grant them copyright on the questions?

I noted also that the question they "gathered" wasn't even updated recently. I would not mind too much to see my question/answer around the 'net if it is useful, as long as they have the decency of updating their contents, and not just live off someone else's bandwidth and efforts.

---

**update**

upon request of clarifications they complied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Defending Attribution Required from the Stack Overflow Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/):

> [W]e adopted a licensing scheme that makes it impossible for us to do anything even partially-semi-evil with our community’s content. Namely, [cc-by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) (aka cc-wiki), which gives everyone the following rights to all Stack Exchange data:
>
> You are free:
>
> - to Share — to copy, distribute and transmit the work
> - to Remix — to adapt the work
>
> Under the following conditions:
>
> - Attribution — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).
> - Share Alike — If you alter, transform, or build upon this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same or similar license to this one.
>
> ---
>
> What are our attribution requirements?
>
> Let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we require that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain, and not use a tinyurl or any other form of obfuscation or redirection.
>
> ---
>
> We’ve been [collecting a list of sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962) that are reposting our data without attributing it correctly — but it’s becoming something of an epidemic lately. Every other day now I get an email or meta report about a real live web search where someone found content that is clearly ripped off, has zero useful attribution, and a bucket of greasy, slimy ads slathered all over it to boot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wise choice (the 'free to remix') on all the line.

Comment: I can't see that questionhub complies with the Share Alike condition, as they doesn't seem to provide any notion about what license the questions is syndicated under, but maybe I didn't understand something about the conditions.

Comment: This snippet also needs the notice about not using javascript to inject the links

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jared said (please read that blog post) I added that one to the list, it is indeed new to us, anyway.

Comment: I contacted them through their website. Let's see what happens. 
Thanks.

Comment: Jeff, I got a reply from them saying that they already comply with the requirements. I think there might be a bigger problem here (either requirement not clear or they don't want to comply). 
In fact, they surely link back to the original post and put the links to the user on the website; however they did not update the post with subsequent edits. 

Hence, there is a discrepancy between the original question and the answer they copied. I will push the envelope a bit further and see what happens.

Comment: --update: they complied and updated my question. I removed the link. Thanks.