# My question is displayed on QuestionHub!

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“copyright” and QuestionHub harvesting questions from SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60957/copyright-and-questionhub-harvesting-questions-from-so)

Basically,  [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499554/android-camera-resolution-with-action-image-capture)  which I posted at SO is also displayed at  [QuestionHub](http://www.questionhub.com/ServerFault/3499554) .

I'd like to know, why this was done and who did it.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60957/copyright-and-questionhub-harvesting-questions-from-so

Comment: At least they're writing "ServerFault" right next to it.

Comment: @Bobby - Strange though as it was posted at SO!

Comment: @Martin Smith: Right...the link is pointing there...odd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All content is licensed via [CC-Wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) and, as such, can be included in other works (like that web site) as long as they correctly [attribute](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) it to SO and you:

> - Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack
>   Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User
>   in some way. It doesn’t have to be
>   obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is
>   fine. **Check, sort of, shows ServerFault when the question is from SO**
> - Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g.,
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)  **Check**
> - Show the author names for every question and answer **Check**
> - Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the
>   source site (e.g.,
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username) **Check**

Comment: miraculously, they do actually follow the attribution requirements! huzzah!

Comment: The only thing that is questionable is the link to the author, it's almost the same color as the background.

Comment: @Holyvier: But they do also have a link on the avatar.

Comment: @Bobby The avatar links to the question on the same site.

Comment: @Holyvier: Oooohhhhh...