# Is this caching on Question Hub legal?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“copyright” and QuestionHub harvesting questions from SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60957/copyright-and-questionhub-harvesting-questions-from-so)

I've found [this site](http://www.questionhub.com/StackOverflow/4239698) that cached my question on SO. Is the SO team was aware of this and is the caching legal?

Comment: @waiwai - true, voted to close.

Comment: I think this might be the meta equivalent of "parsing HTML with regexps"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All questions posted on StackOverflow are subject to a [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).

The site does appear to be fulfilling the "Attribution" terms of that license. They show a StackOverflow logo, a link back to the StackOverflow question, and the name of the person who posted the question (though I had to hunt to find that one; it's in a small gray font).

It's less clear whether they're fulfilling the "ShareAlike" terms. I couldn't see anything on their site explaining that people have rights to copy their content. They may be in violation for this reason.