# Whats Stackoverflow doing here? Some sort of gray-hat SEO?

Tags: discussion, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

Well I just posted this question:

[Dynamic height header in SEO optimized SOC (Source Ordered Content) layout using only CSS, no Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743426/dynamic-height-header-in-seo-optimized-soc-source-ordered-content-layout-using)

And then did some more Google searching to find a solution and stumbled upon this two blogposts:

http://adsensewizard.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/dynamic-height-header-in-seo-optimized-soc-source-ordered-content-layout-using-only-css-no-javascript/

http://need-programmer.blogspot.com/2010/09/dynamic-height-header-in-seo-optimized.html

Which appeared very recently after my potst here and have the exact same text... so they are obviously automated copies of my question...

The links on theese pages are also very weird. For example I cannot click the "Find the answer here" link under the post on "need programmer blog" ... but in source it looks nofollow...

also when signing up i dont remember anything about my questions beeing automatically replicated to other services. its okay for me and its i think legal as well but it should be at least mentioned...

Comment: They're not official mirrors - they're just sites taking advantage of the CC-licensed content.

Comment: I find it strange that you assume that stackoverflow has anything to do with your question being replicated. It's on the web you know... Anyone can see it and make a copy of it and call it his own website. It may be neither legal or moral, but stackoverflow doesn't have to have anything to do with it.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962

Comment: To get it that quick they must be using the API, or screen-scraping. If they're using the API they should be easy to shut down server-side (obviously this won't stop them displaying their cached questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're unofficial sites copying the content, usually to make money from ads or for SEO purposes. Any content you post is licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) (see the footer) and provided in [the data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) and through [the API](https://stackapps.com/).

As long as they fulfill the license's requirements and [provide attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), they're allowed to do this. ([Here's a list of sites that don't.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962))

Answer (score 3):

Both the sites you linked to appear to be violating the terms of the license, specifically the attribution requirement.  The parent sites will probably honor a DMCA takedown request to remove the infringing material
.
See [here](http://en.support.wordpress.com/content-theft-what-to-do/) for wordpress.com, and [here](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/request.py?page=main_tos&blog_ID=9204548932714363053&blog_URL=http://need-programmer.blogspot.com/) for blogspot.com.