# Is developerquestion.com just a ripoff?

Tags: discussion, clone, plagiarism

Is `developerquestion.com` a Stack Exchange ripoff, or is there some valid connection to SE? I.e. does it use the Stack Exchange framework (it really looks very similar)?

Interestingly, it mirrors all the questions of the Stack Exchange sites. Unfortunately, the site does not contain any "about" info at all.

Comment: Sadly, there's [a list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962) of ripoffs that break the rules. For completeness, there's also [a list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953) of valid clones.

Comment: Probably just a ripoff, but who cares? Anyway, thanks for advertising them and increasing their Google-juice a bit.

Comment: @JohnFx it's perfectly valid to point out rip-offs here. It's the explicit standing request of the SO Team to do so

Comment: This site is already listed in the [master list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962).

Comment: @Pekka, I think that at the time JohnFx posted the comment, the URL was a link; not sure if it was `nofollow` -ed.

Comment: @Popular I thought all links were `nofollowed`, excluding website links on your profile at a certain reputation level?

Comment: @Grace, I thought so too, but didn't remember the source, so I hedged.

Comment: @Popular Well, I was going to search for `nofollow` to get the original post, but I think [the search results speak for themselves](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=nofollow "Remember, search expands the HTML!").

Answer (score 18):

A rip-off, and it fails on points 3 and 4 of [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) - send in the ninjas!

Comment: +1 for "Send in the ninjas!" ha!

Comment: It's slow as hell, don't think it will hold long anyways.

Comment: @Martijn: I do not know, if hell is slow, but, hell, it is slow!

Comment: They seem to be complying now.

Comment: @Pekka - gotta love them ninjas. They get the job done.

Comment: @Marc yeah. Although part of me would like to see that crappy ad-heap turned into smoldering ruins rather than complying with the license... But that's the price of freedom (CC-Wiki).

Answer (score 4):

Looks to be a rip off to me.

It isn't listed on the [SE 1.0 post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) or on [Stack Exchange Sites](http://www.stackexchangesites.com)

Also, this is in the footer of the website:

> The questions and answers come from
>   yahoo answers, serverfault.com,
>   stackoverflow.com and superuser.com,
>   and are licensed under the cc-wiki
>   license. site design / logo © 2010
>   developerquestion.com user
>   contributions licensed under cc-wiki

Just looks like it pulls Q&A from all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

A bunch (2619 questions as of now) are tagged "stack overflow".

I like its "About" statement:

> Developer Question is a collaboratively *(adverb that adjective, yea baby)* question and answer site for programmers. It\'s *(escape that apostrophe)* 100% free to post and answer programming questions.