# How do I see the edit history of my question?

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list

Say someone edited my question and I rolled back this edit. Then later, if I wish to use this edit after all, how do I go about doing it? How can I view the Revision history?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll see "edited 48 mins ago" (or however long ago it was) just to the left of your name at the bottom of the question:

> [image]

Clicking this will show the edit history aka Revisions list.

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67447/is-developerquestion-com-just-a-ripoff) as an example.

Comment: Thanks, I just did not know where to click to get to the history :)

Answer (score 8):

I think you want the `revisions`

For this question it will be

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/67469/revisions

So it is made up of:

`site`/posts/`questionNumber`/revisions

Comment: Anyway, this is the only way to view revisions in case of closing/bounty etc that don't cause the "edited" link to appear.