# DeveloperQuestion.com copying StackExchange content

Tags: discussion, content-reuse

These guys appear to be scraping content from StackExchange sites and replacing some of the words with synonyms, possibly to avoid page rank issues with duplicate content.

`http://developerquestion.com`

Take for example this post: `http://developerquestion.com/mysql-errcode-17-cant-createwrite-to-file-tmp/`

The original on ServerFault: [Mysql Errcode: 17 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/...'](https://serverfault.com/questions/199242/mysql-errcode-17-cant-create-write-to-file-tmp/199244#199244)

It's an interesting find. I wouldn't mind the scraping so much if the content was not messed around with. Some of the language doesn't even make sense. They have also ripped off the entire layout of the site.

Comment: Already been asked I'm afraid http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67447/is-developerquestion-com-just-a-ripoff

Comment: Does it really matter, developerquestion.com is to slow for anyone to really use it unless they are asleep.

Comment: @Hogan: Of course, it matters...although you are right, the site is as slow as molasses in Alaska.