# Don't re-post dupe notices on posts that are closed, then reopened, then reclosed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, reopened-questions

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69674/developerquestion-com-copying-stackexchange-content-closed) was closed by the community, reopened by a mod, then reclosed by a mod. Both times it was closed, it was closed as a dupe of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67447/is-developerquestion-com-just-a-ripoff).

Our favorite tireless janitor, the Community user, dutifully posted a "Possible Duplicate:" link when the question was first closed... and then did it again the second time the question was closed, even though it was the same dupe. Can Community be set to not duplicate duplicate messages?

Screenshot in case something changes:

[image: screenshot of question with two Possible Duplicate notices]

Comment: I think it would be preferable that reopening a question removed the block in the first place. That would both solve this issue, as well as the issue that the block is left there when a question was wrongfully closed.

Comment: I am struggling to see why it was reopened in the first place?!

Comment: @Barry Marc explained why in an answer, but deleted it after deciding to close it again. The reasoning was that there was apparently new data in the situation.

Comment: @Grace - ah I see.  I didn't see the answer from Marc. Cheers

Comment: @Barry, not your fault, it's a now-deleted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this update in mid-2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104385), the duplicate box is removed from posts upon reopening. When a question is closed a second time, only one box will exist.

Comment: Since the 2013 revamp to duplicate closing (AFAIK), this is no longer done on old closures. Why is this?