# Don't automatically edit the post to insert "possible duplicate" links

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

When a question is closed as a duplicate, its body is edited to auto-insert the link to that duplicate. I think there are a couple problems with that:

1. If the question is reopened, the auto-generated insert isn't automatically removed.
2. It allows the poster (or anyone else) to roll back the post and protest the closure by reverting the automatic edit.

I propose that the links to the duplicate(s) are moved into a separate "header" field above the post instead of being edited into the body of the question. That way it could be removed or hidden if the question is reopened and it could not be edited or reverted without reopening the question.

There is some potential for loss of functionality there, since right now it is possible to edit the post to either include additional related links or remove obsolete/incorrect ones. That could be addressed by making the "duplicate field" editable at a certain reputation level (10k?) and enabling others to suggest edits for it that'd go through the usual approval/rejection process.

Thoughts?

Comment: I like your idea, but it seems like a lot of work to develop. Is it worth it?

Comment: [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11042058/4) I believe it was by mistake here, and the status here is only half true, the second issue wasn't even answered by @Jeff.

Comment: Unbelievable. "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced" - **guys, this was a feature request, stop closing everything here on MSE!!!** I honestly think the team need to restrict our powers here if this keeps going like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We've implemented Tim's suggestion.

Upon *reopen*, anything from

> Start of post, `>` ... `<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->`

**will be automatically removed from the post**. So edit that block at your peril!

---

> **Editor's note:** This functionality was removed after the duplicate close reason was modified to show an automatic box instead of editing in the duplicate list. If you reopen a question that was closed before the change and thus has the old edited-in banner, you must remove it manually.

Comment: Are the potential duplicates then not displayed at all anymore? Those questions might still contain useful information, even if the question got reopened.

Comment: no -- they would be removed, as that was Tim's suggestion. If the question is a duplicate but then reopened, the implication is that it is *not* in fact a duplicate. Did you have a specific example in mind?

Answer (score 12):

Wouldn't most of this be resolved if everything above (and including):

```
<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

... was removed when a post was re-opened? I'm not quite sure why it *isn't*, so perhaps it should be.

However, we'd probably also want to prevent people from inserting that line unless wrapped in a code block.

Comment: That'd work, too. That's what I started with and then just figured I'd try taking it a step further. :) Looking at the post votes, I think maybe I should've stuck with my original thought.

Comment: @Anna Lear, I don't think it's a bad idea, it just seems kind of complex.

Comment: great idea, we probably should have always done this. Implemented per my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. If the question is reopened, the auto-generated insert isn't automatically removed.

This seems like it would be possible to implement without any major system or UI changes.

> 2. It allows the poster (or anyone else) to roll back the post and protest the closure by reverting the automatic edit.

They can also insert big, all-in-caps rants. These shenanigans don't necessarily help their cause though.

> That could be addressed by making the "duplicate field" editable at a certain reputation level (10k?) and enabling others to suggest edits for it that'd go through the usual approval/rejection process.

It *sounds* like you're really asking for a feature that would prevent the post's author from messing with the duplicate links. I'd be in favor of this, though I'm not sure how wide-spread the problem is; not convinced we need a separate field + edit system though.