# How new duplicate suggestion view works

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I recently saw in a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722327/how-to-merge-register-php-to-html)

> [image]

The question was not closed yet.

> [image]

So it looks like a new feature on my question.

When does that duplicate suggestion appears?  Does it appear on the first close vote cast?

> [image]

Then why post the above autocomment

Comment: Problem demonstrated right here. :)

Comment: @Mysticial my main question is that why that possible duplicate of bla message ?

Comment: It isn't really a dupe. It appears as soon as the first close-vote is cast. But I'm just highlighting the problem described in the other question.

Comment: And now I've demonstrated the problems with that by blindly voting to agree with the first vote.

Comment: Don't delete it. I'm using it as a demonstration of the problem. I've linked it from the other one.

Comment: @Mysticial ok sire will keep it ..

Comment: Interesting, the moment I cast my first reopen vote on it the duplicate box disappears again

Comment: @TimYiJiang that is more annoying .. to remove banner in just one ro vote ...

Comment: @Tim: now this is really annoying, this is closed as duplicate and there is no link to the duplicate…

Comment: And the new possible duplicate box isn't part of the revision history anymore, either.  New features, bumpy road and all that.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166527/stop-generating-possible-duplicate-comments and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166427/automatic-insertion-of-dupe-banner-after-just-one-close-vote-is-vulnerable-to-ab