# Stop generating "possible duplicate" comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

When a question has pending close votes, the system now adds a banner indicating that the question might be a duplicate:

[image: This question may already have an answer here: "mkdir foo; svn mv * foo"]

But the first user to vote still generates a possible duplicate comment:

[image: possible duplicate of "mkdir foo; svn mv * foo" -- Gilles 1 hour ago]

Those comments were always a hack, just like editing the link into the top of the post. The banner eliminated the need for the latter; can we stop generating those comments too?

Comment: Ah, the banner appears after the first duplicate vote?  I didn't know that; I'm a mod, so my votes are always binding.

Comment: Also we should stop *removing* all comments linking to the duplicate

Comment: Question: Is it ever relevant to point out to the close-voter that it isn't a duplicate, or otherwise engage the close-voter in discussion via comments? I've done that many times, without the auto-comment it's not possible.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, first vote enters it. Rather annoying I think (even as a close-voter). But I'll give it some time to see if my "CHANGE BAD!" response goes away.

Comment: @WesleyMurch it's relevant to point out to future close voters/potential reopeners that it might not be. But there's not much reason to refer *directly* to a specific close voter like that in most cases (after all you can't un-vote)

Comment: @BenBrocka: The only thing I can think of (reason to target the specific user) is the close voter commenting "Oops you're right" which is a good deterrent to would-be closers, or perhaps making a mental note to reopen later if the question is wrongly closed by robo-reviewers/closers. Seems like not a big deal, but I wanted to point it out.

Comment: Excellent point! @Wesley it's not relevant to the closer himself since he can't undo or retract the vote, but it's useful for other users, so when seeing  a question wrongly marked as dupe by all means add a comment saying "no it's not a dupe" and explain why.

Comment: @Ben, are (non-automated) comments that happen to link to duplicates indeed removed again? Then I guess I need to remove my answer at [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified/).

Comment: @Arjan yeah, if a non-auto generated one links to it, it seems to be removed just like an auto-generated one. I remember being annoyed to find a comment of mine had disappeared like that

Comment: Earlier I figured I still liked that comment when one votes to close as a duplicate, [but a majority of others vote with different reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166516/entering-a-code-block-on-stack-overflow-seemingly-inefficient). ([Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mOOEc.png)) But I guess Michael is right about that not justifying using auto comments for that.

Comment: And Earlz noted about those auto comments, when I still found them useful: *"I could see this being less useful on newer stackexchanges. The reason this is so useful here and on SO is because it has many questions which remained open even thought they were discussion or shopping questions, so when a similar question comes in, it gets closed as a discussion question, but there is a good duplicate as well."*

Comment: No thanks. If it gets reopened, the visible link to the near-duplicate is gone. There may be a lot of value in near duplicates for people searching for a solution to a problem, so I think the auto-comment should stay.

Comment: @AndrewC So...keep the link in that case? My point is that now that the system has built-in support for showing duplicate links, we shouldn't be generating comments anymore

Comment: People would complain that the system was still showing a duplicate when the (high-rep) users had descided it wasn't. They'd call it a bug and feel like they couldn't get justice. As a comment, it's clear it had its time, and the disussion following it is evident.

Comment: But, @Andrew, auto-comments would be deleted when the question is closed as a duplicate anyway, and would not automatically reappear when it's reopened at a later time. (Even *edited* auto-comments [are often deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified/).)

Comment: See [Jarrod's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166527/stop-generating-possible-duplicate-comments/166528#comment490215_166545): *"the reason the comment was kept was because it provided inbox notifications"*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of the latest build, only the question asker will see the banner while a question is still open - it will be hidden from everyone else.  After closure, everyone will see it.

The comments will continue to be generated when flagging to close, since this will ping the question asker via the global inbox.

Also after closure, the "Linked" questions sidebar will start to include links to the originals, in case you miss the banner at the top of the question.

Comment: Do 3k's still see the banner before it's closed?

Comment: No, only the question asker will see the banner before the question is closed.

Comment: Ah. I like this! So this completely closes the [loophole for abuse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166427/automatic-insertion-of-dupe-banner-after-just-one-close-vote-is-vulnerable-to-ab).

Comment: Nicely done. Will there be any official statement about all those recent changes in the dupe mechanism or only those answers you recently left?

Comment: @JarrodDixon Could this be extended to other close reasons as well? See my recent question here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278244/should-users-be-informed-when-a-question-is-flagged-vote-to-close-rather-than-af

Comment: There is the issue that the auto generated comment may be hidden, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296973/do-not-hide-possible-duplicate-of-comment-when-there-are-lots-of-comments

Comment: *"The comments will continue to be generated when flagging to close, since this will ping the question asker via the global inbox."* Why not cut out the middleman? Send the notification directly to the asker's inbox. Why is the comment required to achieve that?

Comment: @MaskedMan because it's an ugly hack, hijacking existing functionality instead of writing new code. Why it needs to be posted in my name, however...

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason the system still adds a comment automatically is because users with less than 3k can't see the banner, so I guess the comments have a reason.  I want to know why the banner was added though.

I found this out today  [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7996415#7996415).

Comment: This feature request might end up evolving into "use the banner for everything the comments are currently used for"

Comment: What?!! Who the fluff is the banner for, then?!

Comment: I honestly don't know who the banner was added for,  or why it was added.  It seems rather weird to me.

Comment: It also generates an inbox notification to the question asker.

Comment: @JarrodDixon The banner sends an inbox notification?

Comment: Sorry, no... the reason the comment was kept was because it provided inbox notifications.

Comment: @Jarrod, I noticed that closed duplicates are no longer in the "Linked" list of the duplicate. Like [Don't exclude results because of quoted punctuation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/dont-exclude-results-because-of-quoted-punctuation) does not link back to the closed [Exact search syntax matches only full words](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167764/exact-search-syntax-matches-only-full-words). Is that the expected behaviour? (I *think* this was different, earlier.)

Comment: @Arjan those sidebar "Linked" questions will soon be back in the next build