# What could be wrong with this comment?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

Yesterday, there was a comment in: [Spiteful downvoting? Two fast DVs to my unrelated posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178703/165773)

Comment has been deleted and I would like to understand what could be wrong with it?

Per my recollection, comment text was about as follows:

> Vote reversal script won't catch this. My theory is, some users aware of how script works, do this to indicate dislike of something you did. This happened to me more than once and frankly, I sometimes do that myself. By the way, suggested dupe is wrong: this is *not the case* addressed in the answer to [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/165773)

Comment: Assuming it wasn't your own comment, then the phrase, "I sometimes do that myself", might have been an admission of guilt of vote-fraud.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question was closed as a duplicate of that question (and later reclosed with a different target). This was almost certainly an automatic mechanism that removes comments with links to the duplicate target under the assumption that those are not obsolete.

Comment: Not if the comment has a significant amount of "other stuff" besides the link.

Comment: I might have missed it but I didn't think there was an exception for that.

Comment: The comment was deleted by community which supports that. There are no flags and the timestamps match as best I can make out on mobile.

Comment: Yes this is annoying. Sometimes I see/write some useful comments linking the duplicate question and when the question is closed the comment is deleted automatically.

Comment: @Mysticial I requested something like that (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified), but it is not clear if it was ever implemented.

Comment: @MadScientist Hmm... Unless my memory is borked, I do recall seeing a few times on SO where I posted a link with explanation, and it *didn't* get deleted when the question got closed as a dupe of the link.

Comment: In my experience, dupe closures auto-delete only canned comments, like those generated by close votes. For example, in the same question, the very first comment refers the dupe link but it "survived" the closure: [It's called serial downvoting, and...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178703/spiteful-downvoting-two-fast-dvs-to-my-unrelated-posts?lq=1#comment539614_178703)

Comment: @Mysticial It could be that the script deletes only the first comment with the link and leaves later ones in place. Unless my memory is borked in the same way, some comments linking to the dupe target do survive the closure.

Comment: @Mysticial - In my experience the script can even delete comments that only contain "other stuff". [Example here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167591/why-was-my-comment-auto-deleted)

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for pointing to [Flexo's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178798/what-could-be-wrong-with-this-comment/179050#comment539982_178799 "'The comment was deleted by community which supports that. There are no flags and the timestamps match as best I can make out on mobile.'") - I missed it indeed. I deleted my answer and accepted this one