# Exact search syntax matches only full words

Tags: support, bug, search

Inspired by [this question on Meta.AU](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6104/why-does-a-search-for-extra-dependency-give-no-results), we found out that the search engine does have the `"match this"` exact syntax:

[image]

However ... ["extra dependency"](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22extra+dependency%22) returns no results, ["extra dependency?"](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22extra+dependency%3F%22) returns the correct result, and ["xtra dependency?"](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22xtra+dependency%3F%22) fails again. So, apparently the syntax only matches full words.

That's not exactly preferable, I guess. So, the purpose of this post is to please either ...

- explain why this is by design, or if there's a workaround, or
- fix it by matching any substring, not only full words, or
- fix it by adding a wildcard syntax.

Comment: Why would anyone think it was a dupe, this isn't about punctuation?

Comment: I think it is, @Lance. (Unless the OP really wants `xtra` to match `extra` too—despite "words here" in the search help—, but then the example about the question mark is unrelated?)

Comment: @Arjan Oh, that was just an example pattern to support the "matches only full words" claim. I agree on the dupe, btw.