# How long does "This question may already have an answer here" banner appear if the 5 votes are never reached?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

How long does the "This question may already have an answer here" banner appear if the 5 close-as-duplicate votes are never reached?  For example, if a question receives two close-as-duplicate votes, the banner appears.  Does it ever disappear if there are no further close votes?

Comment: I would assume until those votes expire. And only visible to the OP.

Comment: @Bart better post this as answer linking to the post explaining about vote expiry.

Comment: @Bart yes, I concur with @ ShaWizDowArd, when do votes expire?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97594/161198 @Hashbrown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's only shown to the OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166527/stop-generating-possible-duplicate-comments/167980#167980) until the question gets closed. If the close votes expire, it will melt away for all. If it gets closed, then everyone will see it.