# "This question may already have an answer here" never disappears

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

If a question is closed as a duplication, I know how to petition it to be reopened.

However, [there is no way to remove](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175795/how-long-does-this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-banner-appear-if-t) "This question may already have an answer here" from my view.

[Git revert certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068790/git-revert-certain-files/23155910) was not closed, yet for the rest of eternity I will come here and think that it is a duplicate.

[image]

Is there a deliberate reason that this never goes away? It seems strange that only by closing and reopening the question would that disappear.

Comment: You may already be aware,  but if not: only you can see that banner

Comment: @RichardTingle, yes I was aware. ("from my view")

Answer (score 5):

There [very much *is* a way for the notice to vanish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175798/210342):

> If the close votes expire, it will melt away for all. If it gets closed, then everyone will see it.

Once [all close votes have expired](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), the notice should disappear:

> Close votes age away harmlessly after **4** days if the threshold is not reached. Each new close vote resets the timer, and close votes only start expiring [if the question has had 100 views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594).

As the question you're referring to was asked less than 4 days ago, it's safe to assume the close votes have not expired yet.

On top of that, any user with the [*cast close and reopen votes* privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can see the current close vote count. The asker themself (that's you!) can also see the current close vote count (and cast their own close and reopen votes) if they have the [*view close votes* privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

Comment: Ah, so currently, I am waiting for the post to have more than 100 views.

Comment: @Paul It should have already disappeared. There are no active close votes on that question.

Comment: @animuson, it has not disappeared. Is this a bug?

Comment: It'll be a duplicate *flag*. They never expire.

Comment: @michaelb958 Nope, no flags at all. This is probably a bug with close vote *retraction* not getting rid of the banner.

Comment: This is not working for me.  On [this question](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2402/325) on Workplace meta the notice still appears (it's my question), but it has no close votes now.  It was flagged on April 10; I don't see where the flag was handled, but there are no active flags now.  Timeline shows one close review on April 10 (but clicking through doesn't show me anything), so maybe at one time it had one flag and one review vote, but it never reached closure and that was all more than a week ago.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Looks like a bug, then.

Comment: @MonicaCellio did you check [CV queue at TWP meta](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/review/close)? There is a chance that your question is simply stuck in there with dupe flag (my flag by the way! and it is shown `active` to me), because nobody reviewed. If you want it go away, I think all you need is to vote Leave Open. Since you're a moderator over there, this will likely clear it - or, if it won't, then just close and reopen

Comment: It's not in the queue, nor do I see it in the history.  I thought the flag aged away after the four-day close window expired.  Hmm.  I agree I could clear it by closing and reopening, but I'm going to leave it alone for now in case it's needed for debugging.

Comment: @MonicaCellio FWIW last time I checked, [flags to close did not expire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207180/165773 "discussed here")