# Shouldn't the closed-as-duplicate banner update when the title of the target changes?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, hyperlinks, math-se

I recently noticed that duplicate banners (on math.SE, at least) do not update when the target question's title has changed. The specific example I came across was [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18548/264), that was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61482/264) (screenshots below).

Shouldn't we be using a [magically self-titling hyperlink](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49433/161783) for duplicate banners?

(Of course, if the only way of getting the indicated title to change was with an edit, causing the closed question to bump, then I would be totally fine with not having the duplicate banner update).

Something to mention is that on MathJax-enabled sites like math.SE, [the duplicate banner is implemented differently](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1677/264); maybe that causes difficulty with the magic.

---

- Duplicate banner:
  [image]
- Code for duplicate banner:
  [image]
- Current title of the target question:
  [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before February 6, 2013, closing a question as a duplicate caused the duplicate text header to be inserted into the question text. It was static and forever, though it can be manually updated.

On February 6, 2013, [this process changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/189912) and the [duplicates are no longer stored as text in the question itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595/189912):

> - 2013-02-06: The auto inserted text for questions closed as duplicates has been changed to *"This question already has an answer here:"* followed by link to the other question and the number of answers it has. The text is no longer edited into the original question but rather displayed externally. While the question is still open, [only the OP sees the message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167980/152859) and it becomes visible to everyone once the question gets closed. Questions closed as duplicate prior to this change still have the old *"Possible Duplicate:"* text in them.

So for questions closed after that date, you should (hopefully!) see the question title being updated if it changes.