# Replace auto-inserted markdown duplicate banners with real duplicate banners

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Long, long ago, duplicate banners used to be mere markdown in the body of a post. Like, for example, [revision 3 on this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/9730/revisions)

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [particle で　versus particle　と](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/particle-%e3%81%a7%e3%80%80versus-particle%e3%80%80%e3%81%a8)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

Nowadays, of course, duplicate banners are some separate thing - not part of the body of a post.

Would it be possible to convert markdown duplicate banners into real duplicate banners, either as part of some behind-the-scenes batch job, or as part of some magic that happens when one edits a duplicate post that has a markdown banner?

This would also fix this issue, I guess: [Shouldn't the closed-as-duplicate banner update when the title of the target changes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177245/224428).

(Why am I editing duplicate posts that are so old that they predate the current banner system? In this case, to force markdown to be re-baked following this change to the markdown parser: [Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240354/224428). Unlike questions closed for other reasons, I think duplicates ought to be maintained - users may still come across them and find them useful for whatever reason.)

Answer (score 0):

If no automated system is implemented, and you still want to rectify it, you could find them manually using:

```
SELECT TOP 100 id as [Post Link], *
FROM Posts
WHERE CreationDate < '2013-01-01'
    AND Posts.PostTypeId = 1
    AND Body LIKE '%Possible Duplicate:%'
```

<sup>[Adapted from this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/graphicdesign/query/189480/find-text-in-posts)</sup>

On [Data SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Just change `CreationDate` to the date that they changed the system, or get rid of it altogether (make sure to also lose the `AND` after it).

If you cover 100 relatively quickly, it won't update on Data SE until they do the weekly data dump. To find more, select more than the top 100.

Comment: You can find them easily, yes, but, as far as I know, it is impossible to "fix" them - that is, there's nothing you can do to force new-style banners to be attached to a post short of reopening and reclosing the post. You can edit out the old-style banners - but then the post is just bannerless, and that's even worse (you lose the links to the duplicate-parent).

Comment: As well, this will necessarily bump the questions, whereas the Powers could be able to get around this bump.

Comment: @yo' Fair enough, though there isn't a strong case for spending company dollars to implement something special. If it exists already, great, but I haven't heard of anything even similar. (I haven't even seen 10k tools though). The only link I clicked on to check the query was working had both the old and new banners, so I assumed all were like that. I can delete this if you want, I don't mind.

Comment: no need to delete it IMHO if you ask me. It is a good starter idea, just that unfortunately it can't work.