# Please remove 'may already have an answer' from question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, duplicate-questions

[This question about interactive communication between PHP and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716837/provide-feedback-from-python-script-to-php) was voted to be a possible duplicate of [this very basic and poorly-worded question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214231/how-to-send-data-using-post-in-python-to-php).

Could the resulting notice please be removed? It is irrelevant and prevents people from actually reading the question since it looks like a real dupe.

Comment: The question has not been completely closed yet so you are the only one that sees the possible dup message.

Comment: Edit the question and format it correctly ?

Comment: @JoshMein: Thank you, I did not know that was the case.

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk: Thank you, but even if the other question were edited and reworded, it still has nothing to do with my question. I have no idea why it was marked as a possible dupe.

Comment: The ironic thing is, that **this** question on meta.SE _also_ got closed as a dupe of a question that has nothing to do with what was asked here. Is that some kind of joke?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question has not been completely closed yet so you are the only one that sees the possible duplicate message. The following answer explains this feature more:

[Stop generating "possible duplicate" comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166527/stop-generating-possible-duplicate-comments/167980#167980)