# "Duplicate of" banner and link to duplicate removed when a post has reopen votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

[Not sure if feature or bug:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166427/automatic-insertion-of-dupe-banner-after-just-one-close-vote-is-vulnerable-to-ab/166486#comment487182_166427)

[image]()

No. No no no no no no. Now I have a closed duplicate with no link to the duplicate. That is amazingly bad because:

1. What if I want answers? Well...I know this is a dupe but I can't see where. It's [not even in the dang revision history!](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14721235/revisions) (not that I should have to dig into the revision history). Both the banner and the removal of the banner seem to be jumping the gun, but the removal is even worse.
2. What if I have an answer? Well crap, I can't answer this closed question or the mysterious alleged duplicate. $%^&.
3. What if I want to evaluate whether it's a duplicate? I can't reasonably vote to reopen it if I don't know what it was closed as a duplicate of! Suddenly pile-on, foreknowledge or comments are the only way I can evaluate whether it was a dupe.

Do not remove the link to the duplicate until the post is reopened! At first I thought it was a feature, now I'm not sure. Either way, fixitfixitfixitfixitfixitfixit

Comment: For a second there I thought the end of days was nigh.

Comment: It's a feature because smiles happen more on people who are closed without having to do the usual "scrub out the evidence / my question is newer fogs?" edit

Comment: Yeah, I just saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen#reopen/1469008?&_suid=1360179791875010542718407034407) come up in the review queue.  No idea if it needs re-opening, because I have no idea what it's a duplicate of.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Sorry, I think I ruined your great example by voting to reopen. I agree, it's very hard to judge if a question is or isn't a duplicate if you can't find the duplicate link anywhere :)

Comment: @Rachel - hah, no worries.  It pretty much looks the same now as it did before, minus the `[Duplicate]` tag in the title :)

Comment: Also, **fixitfixitfixitfixitfixitfixit**

Comment: I also see the opposite of this happening, if a question has close votes there is a banner like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5tr6v.png).

Comment: @Seth That *is* intentional.

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes, I'm sure it has been.  I was just pointing it out as the issue is related to that change as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

fixedfixedfixedfixedfixedfixed

Comment: Any chance you fixed it too good, causing [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193951/152859)? :-/