# New "marked as duplicate" function breaks reopen reviews?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

Related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166514/does-the-change-in-exact-duplicate-wording-imply-a-shift-in-policy) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166499/duplicate-of-banner-and-link-to-duplicate-removed-when-a-post-has-reopen-votes).

Now, when reviewing reopen votes on questions closed as duplicates, I've got no link anywhere to the question that the closed question is a duplicate of (i.e. the "duplicated" question):

> [image: Faulty reopen review]

Needless to say, without access to the duplicated question it is impossible to judge whether the question being reviewed is truly a duplicate or not, and hence impossible to judge whether a reopen is required or not.

Interestingly, [that particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736807/or-operator-for-if-statement) has now been reopened. I wonder if the absence of a link to the duplicated question resulted in a sufficient number of "I don't see a duplicate - I better reopen it" type reviews.

It looks like I'm not the only one to be bitten by this issue: LittleBobbyTables was busy writing [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166499/duplicate-of-banner-and-link-to-duplicate-removed-when-a-post-has-reopen-votes#comment487552_166499) while I was writing this question.

Comment: Just to note: the previous way was *already* broken. All it did was look for links above the `<!-- auto-inserted -->` comment and add a tab for them. If a user manually edited it out, you were not provided with any duplicates. Bad design from the get-go.

Comment: looks like SO has a hard time ... i never saw that much bug in a single day

Comment: @animuson: I did not know that. Wow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed - thanks for finding it.

Comment: This isn't fixed on Meta as of thirty seconds ago?

Comment: You're not seeing the duplicate banner on [the review you did](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/11786)?

Comment: Sorry Jarrod I misread the bug report - I'm not seeing the old tabs for the duplicate/revisions.  It'd be a pity if they've been removed

Comment: Jarrod: thanks for fixing it! Although I'll second @Rory's comment: where have the dupe tabs gone? Now that the banners are back they're not essential, but from an aesthetics/usability sense they were still useful.