# Note which post a question was closed as a duplicate of in the revision history, even after it's reopened

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, revisions-list

This is the revision history of a post that was closed as a duplicate then reopened, here on Meta. Note that there is no part of the revision which mentions or links to the alleged duplicate:

[image]

The Community user used to edit in a block that explained it was closed as a dupe and had links to each question. It was sort of a hack, since it was *part of the post's text*, which was still editable. But in removing that hack, we lose the link to the possible duplicate.

Sort of but not quite related to ["Duplicate of" banner and link to duplicate removed when a post has reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166499/duplicate-of-banner-and-link-to-duplicate-removed-when-a-post-has-reopen-votes), there's no revision of the closure. The banners appear/disappear as proper now, but now after reopening there's no evidence this post was ever closed as a duplicate.

I really think the revision history should keep a log of *what* question(s) a post was closed was a duplicate of. It could be it's own revision or kept as part of the post closed as duplicate "revision".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This took an insane backfill to get the data in a proper state for display, but it's now done.

For the vast majority of "closed as duplicate" questions, you can see the [chosen originals in the revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14721235/revisions).

There are a few very old closures that we couldn't figure out, but anything closed after `2009-05-20 11:52:52.627` should have something to display.

Comment: But it is not showing banner right now :(. [See example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167989/187824)

Comment: When the question is still open, the banner is only shown to the question asker - [see my answer for more details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167980/3).