# "Possible duplicate" notice not removed after reopening question

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, reopened-questions

I just [reopened this question](https://superuser.com/questions/384920/dig-a-couple-of-files-from-the-restore-partition?noredirect=1), which had been closed as  a duplicate of another.

I navigated away and went to visit the page later, it turns out, the *Possible Duplicate* banner wasn't removed automatically.

> [image]

How come?

Comment: I'd say it was because it was the old style notification rather than the current "modern" UI.

Comment: That should still remove the banner, as it can be identified by the `<!-- End of … text -->` auto-comment.

Comment: Indeed - I suspect that all the old code was removed when closing was revamped.

Comment: [This fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166499/152859) might have caused this. Will ping Jarrod and start a bounty here.