# Remove mark as duplicate

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I know that it has already been requested that a user is enabled to remove his close vote and it has been rejected [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949).

Still a have a case that is a bit more special. I had two tabs of stackoverflow opened and by mistake I marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745829/how-to-read-format-txt-files-in-ruby-on-rails) as duplicate, while in fact I meant to post this in the other tab. Now not only that the question has a close vote that it shouldn't have but also there is a message above that it may already have an answer in another question that has nothing to do with the topic. I would like to request the ability to remove certain types of close votes and in particular duplicate. No matter how the user changes the question I doubt its duplicate state will change.

As you can see I have put a comment to indicate I have erroneously marked the question as duplicate but I believe the not above is far easier to see than my comment below.

Comment: Did you also flag for moderator attention, in case *they* can remove a close-vote in this severely rare edge-case? =)

Comment: @J.Steen Can they? I am certain even moderators can't remove any close vote

Comment: This is being actively discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166427/automatic-insertion-of-dupe-banner-after-just-one-close-vote-is-vulnerable-to-ab

Comment: @Mysticial thank you for that link. However I am asking for the functionality that a user is able to remove his own close vote, which differs slightly from the abuse case, I think.

Comment: @izomorphius I honestly don't know. I've never asked. =)

Comment: @izomorphius Read the answers. Basically all these problems (including the potential for abuse) are all stemming from the fact that the banner cannot be removed. So we are discussing how to change the system to fix this.