# Removing the duplicate mark after editing

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

If after being marked as duplicate, a question is edited to show how it is different from a previously asked question, can the *duplicate* mark be removed?  
 
I've seen various discussion about tackling duplicate on the site for e.g. here [Remove mark as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166593/remove-mark-as-duplicate),  but no clear answer has been given about what I'm asking.

Comment: Are you talking about this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949298/detect-conflicts-between-packages-in-r

Comment: Yes. Moreover, the answer for the previously asked question was less detailed than the one I've received.

Comment: Simply editing a question doesn't necessarily mean it's no longer a duplicate. You really need a human to tell the difference and make the decision.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. Is there anyone who check the edits? But my queries have already been answered by Manishhearth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. Flag it with a custom message, asking for the post to be reopened.

Also, note that when you make an edit, the post goes into the reopen queue, where others review it.

Anyway, if you're talking about [Detect conflicts between packages in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949298/detect-conflicts-between-packages-in-r) there's not much point in removing the duplicate banner, since you already got a good answer. Still, good thing to be consistent.

Comment: It's not that I absolutely want to remove the duplicate banner for this particular question, but when I saw the message _If those answers do not fully address your question, please_ **edit this question to explain how it is different**, I was wondering what's the use of editing if the banner doesn't disappear.  Sorry for being noobish and thanks for the answer.