# User with review super powers

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, binding-vote

Take a look on [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875362/cpilko?tab=summary). Ordinary user, no diamond no text in the About Me indicating he's employee or anything like that.

Now sift through his [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875362/cpilko?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

- [Exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1505734)

> [image]

- [Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1505733)

> [image]

The user has a binding vote when reviewing suggested edits... he's also not OP of any of those posts.

This is NOT case of clicking "Improve" as well, in such case the review action is "Edit" and it's rejected by our dear Community user, not the reviewer.

What's going on? I also checked the [Team page](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) and he's not there. (Checked the HTML source for the links, as his display name is not his real name)

Marking this as feature request in case this power was granted on purpose, then it's better to add some indication e.g. special symbol next to display name and something official here on Meta or in the blog.

Comment: @Kate no. He did not choose improve. He clicked the ordinary reject button and gave a rejection reason.

Comment: I see multiple reviewers in both of your exhibits.

Comment: @balpha Huh? For Exhibit A I see two rejects, and for Exhibit B I see two Approves and one Reject...

Comment: @balpha it need 3 same reviews (all of this happens on Stack Overflow, not here on Meta). Unless it has been changed again in the last few minutes? Edit: no, it wasn't changed. [Recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1505857) where it needed 3 mortal reviewers.

Comment: @Kate no. I've reviewed over 5000 suggestions and saw my share of all kinds of decisions. This is the first of this kind. Even if what you say was true, that user would have shown up in the revisions of the post right? Well, [he's not](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4582701/revisions).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd you're right, I just tested. It doesn't come out the way you show in your screenshot. Weird!

Comment: @Kate lol glad I could finally convince you!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd as you know I can't retract my close vote. But I would if I could.

Comment: My bad, you are of course right.

Comment: Looking at recent reviews not *all* of his votes appear to be binding [link](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1474449), so it's not like the system just thinks he's a moderator or something.

Comment: So do we just edit out the "The question may already have an answer here:" text since this isn't a dupe?

Comment: @Lance it's no longer part of the post so can't be edited out. Only option is close then reopen.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, thanks, never realized that.

Comment: @Lance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166427/automatic-insertion-of-dupe-banner-after-just-one-close-vote-is-vulnerable-to-ab

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That user does their review duty on *facebook*.stackoverflow.com. And the setting on that  site for "number of votes required to suggest or reject an edit" wasn't synchronized with Stack Overflow proper, so it fell back to the network-default value of 2, and thus when the user had the second vote, it counted as final. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: I suspected that, but I didn't see reviews with facebook related tags.  Does the review queue from the facebook site show all SO review content, not just filter for facebook content?

Comment: @Servy Yes, it does.

Comment: Seems strange that any synchronisation would be required. For a robust system, the value should be taken from one, authoritative place, regardless of which subsite is being used as a graphical interface. No?