# Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I understand that this may be a duplicate, but the highly voted answer posted at [Can we re-request features that were declined a sufficient while ago?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/can-we-re-request-features-that-were-declined-a-sufficient-while-ago) suggests that the best course of action is to re-request.

---

[Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) was an incredibly popular question, and I've just came across another instance of a place where I want to rescind my close vote.

Since Jeff Atwood isn't unilaterally declining popular feature requests like this anymore, can I request that that the `Status-Declined` tag be removed from that question, and that the feature be re-considered.

Comment: You can ask, but *why*? What've you got to add to the discussion that's not already on the old post?

Comment: @Shog9 I think it's fair to say that the old post is a bit... old. And that people are looking to see if the opinion has changed among the higher-ups.

Comment: This is a perfect time to [further plug my actual solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167514) which I had posted there. :)

Comment: And http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167503/can-we-please-rescind-close-as-dupe-votes-or-at-least-flag-for-special-casing for dupes, too. I liked animuson's solution, and I'm disappointed it doesn't seem to be moving forward. IMO this is an important feature.

Comment: @Shog9 that red `status declined` tag and the clear age of the post makes me afraid that simply bumping that would not make the feature  be seriously considered at this point.

Comment: While we're here, can I ask for the ability to remove your "What have you tried" comment, after I edit my question to put what I have tried?  You won't remove that comment yourself (nobody ever does), so why would I depend on you to come back and rescind your close vote?

Comment: @RobertHarvey  Last I checked, You actually do have the ability to remove your own comments

Comment: My point is that people seldom take advantage of that ability.  They litter the site with `canihaztried`, and then leave those comments there forever, for the whole world to see.