# Does StackExchange monitor content scraping?

Tags: discussion

Just got a notification that someone from a Wordpress site linked to an old article of mine. Upon investigation, I realized it was because a content scraper ripped off my StackOverflow question from here: [Workaround to prevent Facebook "Like" cross-domain error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980973/workaround-to-prevent-facebook-like-cross-domain-error)

and put it up here: http://techforumnetwork.com/techqns/workaround-to-prevent-facebook-like-cross-domain-error-2/

Although I know content scraping questions have been asked before (i.e.: [Is developerquestion.com just a ripoff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67447/is-developerquestion-com-just-a-ripoff)), is the team actually monitoring this? TechForumNetwork.com obviously has failed the "attribution required" test. I do feel uncomfortable that my questions are being reposted with my username across the net without knowing the implications.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange only monitors scraping that does not follow the required attribution rules ([/legal, sec.3](https://stackexchange.com/legal)).  Such violators should be reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here).