# Is this a mirror site affiliated with SO or a clone?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117659/problem-uploading-ipad-4-2-app-to-apple

... --> here, with an ad in front. `http://www.expert.tc/topic.php?id=93952`

Just wondering...

Comment: Thx for editing. Haven't checked yet how to unautolink urls.

Comment: I just wrapped it in an inline code element by wrapping `s around it.

Comment: Should be retagged to [`clone`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's clearly an independent site; as you can see, the question was asked 2012 years ago. Stack Overflow didn't exist back then.

Okay, just kidding. Yes, this is a site that takes content from Stack Overflow and presents it without [proper attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). It's already in the [list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962).

In other words, those are bad guys.

Comment: Without bad guys, there is no need for good guys.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up balpha, just thought I'd report it. Grr, bad guys! *shakes fist*

Answer (score 1):

No, this site is not affiliated with SO. It is one of the many sites that scrapes content from SO and then presents it alongside their own ads hoping to make a quick buck.