# Is everything added to SO automatically CC licensed?

Tags: discussion, licensing

Is all the content here on SO CC licensed?

I have seen some snippets of code which weren't officially CC licensed.

What if poster doesn't note it is licensed.

Can I get in trouble for using it in my projects?

Comment: IANAL, but if you ever hit it big, while improperly using *any* piece of content, lawyers are pretty much guaranteed to come a-knocking. Anyway, in this case, if you keep the [attribution guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), you should be all right. See also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90552/etiquette-for-using-stackoverflow-answers) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the footer:

> user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

The license that applies is [CC-Attribution (BY)-Share Alike (SA)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), with special [Stack Exchange attribution rules](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). This only applies to questions, answers, comments, tag wikis, and privilege descriptions, but does not apply to SE trademarks and text, such as site logos, which are the property of Stack Exchange, Inc.