# Website in violation of attribution policy?

Tags: discussion, support, attribution

Not sure what can be done besides contacting the [offender](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72881/is-my-website-compatible-with-stackoverflow-content-terms-and-conditions) or sending a DMCA notice, but programmingbulls.com seems to clearly be ripping off Stack Overflow content without <strike>proper</strike> any [attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).  For example, this [post](http://programmingbulls.com/facebook-help-unauthorized-ip-address-exception) is a copy of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322004/facebook-unauthorized-ip-address-exception)  Whats odd though, is that some of the words have been slightly modified.  They are also outranking Stack Overflow on Google when searching for "Facebook Unauthorized IP address exception".

More examples:

[Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357166/how-to-compare-against-multiple-strings-in-xslt), [Cloned](http://programmingbulls.com/xml-xslt-comparing-against-multiple-strings)

[Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357279/what-is-the-output-format-of-a-webcam), [Cloned](http://programmingbulls.com/hardware-webcam-output-format)

Basically, all posts listed on this [page](http://programmingbulls.com/tech).

Comment: If, its only one question, maybe the OP posted it to two different sites?

Comment: That was only one example.

Comment: @Gamecat:  Valid point.  I've cross-posted several questions over at MSDN myself.

Comment: There are subtle differences between the questions that do make it look like it may have been cross-posted.  No greeting on the SO version for one (and it wasn't just edited out, it was never there)...

Comment: Except there is no place to submit entries there so I doubt everyone is cross-posting there.  I'm guessing he has some script to do some kind strange text replacement.  I added more examples.

Comment: @OffBySome oh my you seem to be correct, as most of those examples have some generic greeting added.  He's not only taking the content and not attributing it, he's taking it and **making it worse**.

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo yep - seems like your typical adsense scam.

Comment: @OffBySome seems weird to have asked about how to be compliant (your first link) and then just throw it out the window, but with the greeting addition I can't see it being anything other than purposeful modification

Comment: How about we just fire off an email to him/her and ask politely to begin with? I can do that easily enough.

Comment: Email sent, see my own answer below with the content.

Comment: It's fun to stay at the D-M-C-A....

Comment: He has replied, see my edited answer. Looks like this will work out OK.

Comment: Is it just me or are they just copying questions and no answers?  I'm not seeing any answers on any of the posts.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo salutations are now [automatically removed from posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) when they are created. When this was implemented, it was also applied retroactively. The questions were likely the same initially, but the version on [so] has changed since it was scraped.

Comment: @nhinkle those questions are from yesterday and the filtering started over a week ago, so they should never have hit the website or any of its data feeds with those greetings

Comment: Hm, odd. In that case, I take back my comment.

Comment: As for outranking search results: I've started to tell Google to block such results, for me. That does require me to be logged in to Google (or, for example, Gmail), and might give Google even more information about me than they already have. But I *hope* Google will use the blocking for their final ranking too – if many people explicitly block results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I took it upon myself to send off an email to programmingbulls@gmail.com, the email address listed on the [Contact us](http://programmingbulls.com/feedback) form related to website comments:

---

**Attribution required for Stack Overflow content**

Hi.

Did you know that you are in violation of the attribution requirements rights for the content on Stack Overflow?

That's right! The posts you lifted (here: http://programmingbulls.com/tech) require you to attribute the contents of those back to Stack Overflow, where you got them.

Evidence of copying:

- http://programmingbulls.com/xml-xslt-comparing-against-multiple-strings copied from [How to compare against multiple strings in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357166/how-to-compare-against-multiple-strings-in-xslt)
- http://programmingbulls.com/hardware-webcam-output-format copied from [What is the output format of a webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357279/what-is-the-output-format-of-a-webcam)

The requirements are listed here:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Specifically, this:

> **Attribution** — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).

Evidently you have failed to comply with the requirements.

Do you plan on changing the site to show the required attribution?

There is a post on meta.stackoverflow.com about your website - [Website in violation of attribution policy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95175/website-in-violation-of-attribution-policy) - you should log on and weigh in with your thoughts on the matter.

--
Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen

---

I'll edit in any replies I get but I have low hopes.

---

I got a reply about a minute ago:

> HI Lasse,
>
> I had tried to be  compliant with SO postings. See here: [Is my website compatible with Stackoverflow Content Terms and Conditions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72881/is-my-website-compatible-with-stackoverflow-content-terms-and-conditions)
>
> Let me fix these postings as well this week to avoid any violation.

---

Basically, if he follows through, and considering he posted in 2010 about his site and asked for help, I have no doubt he will comply with the requirements.

Comment: Pitchforks and torches at the ready

Comment: I hope it won't come to that, let's see what he does with some gentle and polite prodding. If he adds the required attribution, he's well within his rights to do what he did, that's what the license is all about. So let's see what happens.

Comment: Regardless, it's still a low quality spam site that adds absolutely no value to Stack Overflow content. And actually makes it worse by changing the content for the worse. What is Stack Overflow's stance on distastefully changing the content?

Comment: That is an altogether different question or problem, I agree. However, if he complies with the attribution rights, I'm not sure there is any more that can be done. I mean, you can't say "This is for everyone as long as they attribute the original source. Oh, except for you, but yeah, for everyone".

Answer (score 0):

The navigation on that site is pretty horrible, so it's difficult to get a better idea of just what's going on.

A handful of their copied questions come with a link back to SO:

[image: Screenshot with "View Stackoverflow Question" visible]

Comment: The link is not on the post I linked.  And the link alone doesn't meet attribution guidelines.

Comment: Ha! So it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to be  compliant with SO postings earlier as well. See here: [Is my website compatible with Stackoverflow Content Terms and Conditions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72881/is-my-website-compatible-with-stackoverflow-content-terms-and-conditions)

Let me fix these postings as well this week to avoid any violation. Sorry.

Comment: How about just dont put put Stack Overflow content on your spam site to try and generate ad sense money without adding any value to the internet?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to respond.