# How to read the Stack Overflow thread

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I saw in lot of sites, if I post a thread on Stack Overflow, I see that thread on their sites. I am not sure, how is it possible?

I have a site, it's just for fun, not an commercial motivation,

I want to mirror a Stack Overflow PHP thread on my site, what is the step-by-step procedure?

Comment: Remember that **[attribution is required](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962)**. Some of the sites you talk about are in violation of those terms. Also, most of them get Stack Overflow content by [scraping the HTML delivered from stackoverflow.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the [Stack Exchange API](https://stackapps.com/).