# How did a Stack Overflow question get copied on another website?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

I had asked a question on Stack Overflow and got some helpful answers too.

I was looking for more information when I came across this: `http://www.devcomments.com/q570548/What-first-class-citizen-function` which had the same question as it is.

How did the question got copied?

It also links to the users who answered the question.

Comment: Haha, devcomments: "Doing the same thing as StackOverflow, only worse, and slower"

Comment: If you want to help push the copycat site out of the google search results, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/80509#80509) post.

Comment: @lazyr Google doesn't use personnal blocklist to modify his global search result. The only thing it will affect is your own search result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow content is cc-wiki licensed, if you look very carefully at the very bottom of every page it says:

> > user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

If you click on the associated link, it takes you to a blog post with the following detail:

If you republish this content, we **require** that you:

1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
3. Show the author names for every question and answer
4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)