# Any simple way to block all Stack Overflow knock-off websites?

Tags: discussion, league-of-justice

So Google recently released [a "block" feature](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/hide-sites-to-find-more-of-what-you.html) which can allow a user to easily block any domain if we find it to be less than useful.

I would *love* to block the [Copied-From-Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers) (particularly the websites without attribution).

However, I don't have the time (or inclination) to block each website specifically. I'll continue to block a website as they spam my results, but is there an automated way to block all these Stack Overflow knockoffs with a fast and efficient script?

Answer (score 5):

The Chrome extension has an import/export feature, so it would be reasonably easy for there to be a list of the sites somewhere in the appropriate format, and just periodically import them manually. I doubt that new ones pop up *that* often.

Comment: So now, the question is, where is the best place to have that list? Would it be good to have somewhere here? Or on a different site?

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to the extension so that I can use the list provided by @Will? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my list; it contains quite a few knockoff sites

[check the revision history; hit View Source to get it formatted correctly!]

Answer (score 2):

[There's a Chrome Extension for that!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gledhololmniapejefjfocffkhoamlll)