# I found a SO clone, is this the place to report it?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, clone

I saw similar posts before, so I am reporting one I did not find already posted here: `nujk.com`

Edit: I found it's not a clone, but just takes the content from SO and displays ads.

Comment: Does it have attribution for the posts? If not then it definitely needs reporting.

Comment: I don't think there is need to report this: It's not copying content from SO. Cloning the UI is fair game

Comment: Correction, they seem to be scraping data from all sorts of places like [this one](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/win2003/t1197695277). THat is probably not okay. Not sure whether any SO content is among it, though - I can't see any

Comment: that's some weird-ass usernames and WTF the font about? Post a link here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962

Comment: also possible related, depending on if they are using the inferface or scraping answers too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: @Pekka `http://www.nujk.com/global-javascript-variable-scope-why-doesn-39-t-this-work` versus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685388/global-javascript-variable-scope-why-doesnt-this-work seem the same, except for the user names? (The very first I searched for.)

Comment: @Arjan ah, fair enough. All the ones I searched for were from elsewhere. Well, in that case, this site definitely needs burninating. The user names are indeed weird, too

Comment: @tombull89 Oh god, chiller... I hate that font. Looks like they copied not only the questions but also the UI. All of the 'users' asking and answer the questions however have been replaced with fake ones. This is horrible...

Comment: @Arjan - they're definitely using API to grab "our" content, problem is they make it appear as it's their own.

Comment: @Arjan: That's a clear violation.  No links back to the site they scraped, plus they're replacing the names of people who posted content with fake names.

Answer (score 4):

This website is really fishy for the following reasons:

1. No footer
2. The "author" according to meta tags is *189881000@qq.com*
3. This is found in their source code: `<div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow" id="adzerk2">`

All in all, I strongly belive that website is indeed illegal.